# ASP.NET MVC importing XML files to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have several hundreds of XML files with something similar to following format but with lot more objects and elements inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person Version="3.13.12.0" Type="Design">
    <Input>
        <InputClass1>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </InputClass1>
        <InputClass2>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </InputClass2>
        <InputClass3>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </InputClass3>

    </Input>
    <Output>
        <Type1>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </Type1>
        <Type2>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </Type1>
        <Type3>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </Type3>
        <Type>
            <elem1>Value</elem1>
            <elem2>Value</elem2>
        </Type3>
    </Output>
</Person>
```

Each file has a unique file name in my case. Users may replace the file. So previous version should be recorded.  I have a ASP.NET MVC(API) web project. What would be the best way to record these files and query them from MVC/API controller ?

Comment: Serialize the XML files into PERSON objects, save the objects to a DB with a unique id. When you need to retrieve the data again simply instantiate the returned records from DB as Person Objects.

Comment: SQL Server if it is your engine, can do it for you

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is integrating your app with a SQL Server database, since SQL Server does have its own powerful engine to query and manipulate XML. So you create stored procedures and invoke them from your asp.net app (with ADO.NET)

See [this sql server xml tutorial](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/92778/)

Another Choice would be using [`Linq` to manipulate xml.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)